# iPhone Overwritten Data

Tags: data-recovery

How to get back over overwritten data?

My case: photos and videos from iPhone?

My phone updated and restored and I never got to back up my phone.

Where does the overwritten data go and how do I get it back?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You might want to explain how data was written over in some detail for us to help you more than the general assumption that you restored the entire device or chose (or allowed someone) to erase the entire device. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

Answer (score 2):

If you restored your iPhone from a different backup, or as a new device, then you would need to restore again from the correct backup.

There is no recoverable data once a restore has been completed.
The devices are hardware encrypted & once the encryption keys are deleted, that's it, I'm afraid.